# Getting the second part of a URL through PHP

Tags: php, parse-url

I'm trying to setup a page that pulls just a part of the URL but I can't even get it to echo on my page.

Since I code in PHP, I prefer dynamic pages, so my urls usually have "index.php?page=whatever"
I need the "whatever" part only.

Can someone help me. This is what I have so far, but like I said, I can't even get it to echo.

```
$suburl = substr($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"],strrpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],"/")+1);
```

and to echo it, I have this, of course:

```
echo "$suburl";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your url is `index.php?page=whatever` and you want to get the **whatever** from it

if the part is after **?**  ( abc.com/xyz.php?......)  , you can use $_GET['name']

---

for your url `index.php?page=whatever`

use :

**$parameter= $_GET['page'];**      //( value of $parameter will be whatever )

---

for your url `index.php?page=whatever&no=28`

use :

**$parameter1= $_GET['page'];**  //( value of $parameter1 will be whatever )

**$parameter2= $_GET['no'];**    //( value of $parameter2 will be 28 )

---

please before using the parameters received by $_GET , please sanitize it, or you may find trouble of malicious script /code injection

for url : **index.php?page=whatever&no=28**

like :

```
if(preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/", $_GET['no'])) {
   $parameter2= $_GET['no'];
}
```

it will check, if **GET** parameter **no** is a digit (contains 0 to 9 numbers only), then only save it in $parameter2 variable.
this is just an example, do your checking and validation as per your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get the value of the `page` parameter, simply use the `$_GET` global variable to access the value.

```
$page = $_GET['page']; // output => whatever
```

Comment: I love you.This was the most simple thing ever and I have been pulling my hair out looking for this. I have no idea why this was giving me so many issues, but thank you so much. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use basic PHP function [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) for example:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://site.my/index.php?page=whatever';

$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

var_dump(explode('=', $query));
```

Working code example here: [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=d9145710bd0e60a31121f13d54972b39&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: Note: `split()` function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0. Alternatives to this function include: `preg_split()`, `explode()` and `str_split()`

Comment: Better use [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) on top or you will get problems when you have an url like `?page=whatever&tab=info`. [Example](https://phpize.online/?phpses=9347ab4820f129617eac3ee14388c6d4&sqlses=null)